# How do I remove everything from a Homebrew tap?

Tags: macos, homebrew

There are no good ways to remove everything from a specific tap.
I tried `untap`; it just untaps the tap, but not dealing with the packages
installed from it, and actually reinstalling package installed from it
would result in tapping that specific tap back.

If there are no good ways to uninstall tap along with its packages
Is there any way to list all installed packages and show which tap they are from?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is there any way to list all installed packages and show which tap they are from?

You can list all installed packages with `brew ls --full-name --formula`. Tap’d formulae are prefixed with their tap:

```
$ brew ls --full-name --formula
...
webp
xz
yarn
z
zlib
bfontaine/utils/eq
osrf/simulation/ignition-math3
```

In the output below, `bfontaine/utils/eq` is the formula `eq` from my [`bfontaine/utils`](https://github.com/bfontaine/homebrew-utils) tap. `ignition-math3` is from the [`osrf/simulation`](https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation) tap.

By default, `brew ls` shows formulae on multiple columns. You can force them to display one one column by piping the output to `cat`:

```
$ brew ls --full-name --formula | cat
```

---

> How do I remove everything from a Homebrew tap?

Based on the above, you could do something like this:

```
$ brew ls --full-name --formula | grep '^your/tap/' | xargs brew uninstall
```

Note: if you don’t use `--formula`, `brew ls` also shows [casks](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/), which are special formulæ that install `.app`s.

Comment: if you want to remove all versions of a formulae then you could use - `brew ls --full-name --formula | grep '^your/tap/' | xargs brew uninstall --force`

Comment: @bfontaine I know this is old, but what is '^your/tap'? To remove eq what exactly would go in here? grep bfontaine/utils?

Comment: @todivefor `^your/tap` would be `^bfontaine/utils` if you want to remove everything from bfontaine/utils. To remove only `bfontaine/utils/eq` all you need to use is `brew remove bfontaine/utils/eq`.

Comment: @bfontaine Thank you for the reply. I guess I am confused as to the "^".

Comment: @todivefor it’s to match at the beginning of the string, so that `something-bfontaine/utils` is not matched; only strings that _start_ with `bfontaine/utils` are.